# How would you optimise this javascript if else statement

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have been working on building some platform, I couldn't find any other efficient way to optimise othar than given one. What would be your solution to optimise give multiple if else statement?......................................................................

```
if (response['total_visits'] == visitNumber.val()) {
  visitNumber.css('color', 'green');
} else {
  visitNumber.css('color', 'red');
}
if (response['best_thing'] == aboutCity.val()) {
  aboutCity.css('color', 'green');
} else {
  aboutCity.css('color', 'red');
}
if (response['fav_attraction'] == favAttraction.val()) {
  favAttraction.css('color', 'green');
} else {
  favAttraction.css('color', 'red');
}
if (response['destination_dining'] == destinationDining.val()) {
  destinationDining.css('color', 'green');
} else {
  destinationDining.css('color', 'red');
}
if (response['method_transport'] == transportMethod.val()) {
  transportMethod.css('color', 'green');
} else {
  transportMethod.css('color', 'red');
}
if (response['age_group'] == ageGroup.val()) {
  ageGroup.css('color', 'green');
} else {
  ageGroup.css('color', 'red');
}
if (response['income_level'] == incomeLevel.val()) {
  incomeLevel.css('color', 'green');
} else {
  incomeLevel.css('color', 'red');
}
if (response['visit_purpose'] == onBusiness.val()) {

  onBusiness.css('color', 'green');
} else {
  onBusiness.css('color', 'red');
}
if (response['accomodation_cost'] == accomadationCost.val()) {

  accomadationCost.css('color', 'green');
} else {
  accomadationCost.css('color', 'red');
}
if (response['occupation'] == occupation.val()) {
  occupation.css('color', 'green');
} else {
  occupation.css('color', 'red');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would store them in an object, and use `Object.keys` in order to update the `css`

```
const obj = {
  total_visits: visitNumber,
  best_thing: aboutCity,
  fav_attraction: favAttraction,
  destination_dining: destinationDining,
  method_transport: transportMethod,
  age_group: ageGroup,
  income_level: incomeLevel,
  visit_purpose: onBusiness,
  accomodation_cost: accomadationCost,
  occupation: occupation
};

Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
  if (response[key] === obj[key].val()) {
    obj[key].css('color', 'green');
  } else {
    obj[key].css('color', 'red');
  }
})
```

In the above object, `visitNumber`, `aboutCity...` etc are exactly same objects as what you are using in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), that would make this a whole lot neater.

```
let color = response.total_visits == visitNumber.val() ? 'green' : 'red';
visitNumber.css('color', color);
```

Repeat for the rest of them.